# Test Email Virus Protection

Tags: exchange-2003, anti-virus, mcafee

This is kind of an odd question, but what is a good way to test the virus protection on my Exchange 2003 server?  Sounds kind of odd, and I really don't want to infect anything accidentally if it *doesn't* work...

I am running McAfee Security Service for Exchange and I want to see what happens when it comes across a virus-infected message.

Maybe I should just wait until I get one to see what it does? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Eicar](http://www.eicar.org/anti_virus_test_file.htm) test virus.  Its fake, but will trigger anti-virus software.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about exchange specifically, but you might try the [Anti-Virus Test File](http://www.eicar.org/anti_virus_test_file.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Use the EICAR virus test file. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file .

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure if McAfee supports it, but there's a standard file called the EICAR file that is not a virus, but that almost every anti-virus vendor recognizes as a virus so that you can test AV deployments without actually infecting yourself.  You can find the contents of the file and details on how to use it at http://www.eicar.org/anti_virus_test_file.htm

As for how to do the test, you can send it with a standard client as an attachment but you might run into local AV checks before you get to the server.  I like to use something like [swaks](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/) to send the file to avoid client AV issues

Comment: McAfee support it - all reputable AV vendors support it.